Specify parameter type class in python
I want to specify a parameter in one of my classes to have a more legible code.
All types work (str, int, list, etc.) but not class.
How can I specify that my parameter enemy in the function attack of Character is a class (or even the specific class Enemy)?
class Character:
    def __init__(self, life_stat, attack_stat, healing_stat):
        self.life_stat = life_stat
        self.attack_stat = attack_stat

    def attack(self, enemy):
        enemy.life_stat += -self.attack_stat


class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, life_stat, attack_stat):
        self.life_stat = life_stat

I tried with:
enemy: class

Not working because it wants to create a new class.
enemy: Enemy

Not working because Enemy is not already defined.

Are you talking about python typing? Did you mean: def attack(self, enemy:'Enemy'):?

IIUC add from __future__ import annotations at the top of your module and then (for Python3.7+) you can use enemy: Enemy without problems or place Enemy class definition before Character
